# jQuery preventDefault() not working on first click

Tags: jquery, click, preventdefault

I have the following code

```
$("#logoutLink").click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var dataString = "action=confirm";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "requests.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(msg) {
            if (msg == "success") {
               alert('logged out');
            } else {
                showNotification("error", "" + msg + "");
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            showNotification("error", "Could not log you out at this time, try again.");
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

and a link with id="logoutLink"

the preventDefault doesn't work first time because the login system doesn't refresh the link and adds html content with links, in which is the logout link and therefore the item doesn't exist in html, I know this is the problem, but my question is how would I make it know that html content has been added with link id logoutLink without page refresh?

Comment: so confused. please get a friend to read what you have asked. Please rewrite the question. I have NFI what you want

Comment: haha, ok here is the thing, I have a login system which uses jquery and logs users in without refreshing the page, upon loging in, there is a div with id called options and jquery adds links in that div using .html() method, therefore the original html, when you view source of page doesn't have, and then I have php that chekcs if the user is logged in, and ads those links there (in this case its added directly to html without jquery). Logout is one of the links and when first jquery logs users in and adds the links to that div, logout link doesn't work with .click() method

Comment: my question is how would I make it know that there is a logout link, even though the page is not refreshed, and the links are only added through jquery and not html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is not clear, but it you're adding the link dynamically, you should be using either `.live('click', ...)`, or the new jQuery 1.7 `.on()`.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit confusing, but try using `live()` to bind your event handler:

```
$("#logoutLink").live('click', function(event) {
    // ...
```

See http://api.jquery.com/live/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the click handler `$("#logoutLink").click(function(event) {}` only after the login system adds the links, so I'd do the following

```
function addHandlers(){
    $("#logoutLink").click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         // anything else
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    addHandlers();
});
```

then also call `addHandlers();` when the links are added